# How to send transaction email with transaction email id magento2

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

I want to send transaction email with specific ID(transaction email id) with cron scheduled.

can anyone help me on this

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

> Firstly you create a cron job,for that you can follow this link
>   http://inchoo.net/magento-2/running-cron-jobs-in-magento-2/ after that
>   add below code in construct() method

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
    TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
    LoggerInterface $logLoggerInterface, 
    array $data = [])
{
    $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_logLoggerInterface = $logLoggerInterface;
    parent::__construct($context,$data);
}
```

and in execute() method :

```
try {

        $email='demoemail@gmail.com';//replace with your transaction email id
        $error = false;
        $cname = 'demo';//replace with your receiver name
        $cemail = 'demo@gmail.com';//replace with your receiver email
        $csubject = 'demo send email';
        $sender = [
         'name' => $cname,
         'email' => $cemail,
         ];

        $postObject=array(
         'myname' => $cname,
         'message' => $message,
         'subject'=>$csubject);
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
        $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder
           ->setTemplateIdentifier('mymodule_email_template')
           ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                ]
            )
           ->setTemplateVars($postObject)
           ->setFrom($sender)
           ->addTo($email)
           ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();

         } catch (\Exception $e) {            
            $this->messageManager->addError(
            __('We can\’t process your request right now. Sorry, that\’s all we know.')
        );
        }
```

Comment: ok thanks i will try this and get back to you

Comment: while compile iam getting this error StateInterface does not exist

Comment: Include below line after namespace define

Comment: use \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

Comment: ok thanks.....but how to run the script from root folder

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Include below line before class :

```
use \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
```

Comment: Actually my intension is...I need to send a transactional email template every week( via cron)

Comment: Set a cron which run every week